# PC starts after several attempts

Tags: boot, ssd, dell-optiplex

I have a dell optiplex 7080 tower pc, working fine. But sometimes (not all the time) it fails to boot after after 3 attempts it boots up. I have a Transcend 512GB 220S SSD installed on my PC. Why this is happending?

Can a bad PSU cause this?

Comment: We need a bit more information. Do the lights always come on, do the fans go spinning (indicating that there is power), but there is nothing shown on the screen? Or does pressing the button sometimes literally result in nothing happening (no lights, no fan noise, nothing)

Comment: No everything becomes off.